# Can I use AAPT to add a version code to an APK?

Tags: android, versioning, apk, aapt

I have been told that there is a way to use aapt's `--version-code` option to add/insert a version code into an APK whose manifest doesn't define one. However, I haven't found any examples of people doing this (except for https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/adt-dev/XjehZDzfXhk/g2sWBC37_I4J, which links to a dead page and isn't even the same thing I am trying to do) if indeed it is possible to do.

Currently `aapt d badging example.apk` run on the apk in question returns something like

> package: name='com.example.core' versionCode='' versionName='1.0.0'
>   sdkVersion:'8'

In my manifest I currently have the versionName defined as a string in an xml file, so I can pull it in with something like `android:versionName="@string/app_version_name"` (inside the manifest tag). However, if I try this with the version code it doesn't seem to want to resolve the reference. It tries to literally set the version code to the path I enter and then fails as it isn't an integer.

I've tried to do something like `aapt p --version-code 100 example.apk` but it seems to want to package up a whole project and expects a directory of files as input, not an apk file. (I assume that is the default behavior of `aapt p[ackage]`)

Is it possible to set the version code of an APK after it has been built using the aapt tool? If so, what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution will not use aapt directly, but it will behind the scenes.

You can use [Android APKTool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) to open you APK, alter the  `AndroidManifest.xml`   file, adding the version info; and then use APKTool again to repack. That tool is opensource and uses aapt. Thus you can look at its code to figure out how to do it using aapt directly.

Comment: I am mostly looking for a solution I can add to our current maven build process. For example, the default android build.xml will insert the version code when it runs aapt if you set a certain property. However, I don't have control over the maven aapt calls, so I was hoping to be able to add another one after the apk is made to insert the version code then.

Comment: I ended up opting for the simpler find/replace templated manifest using a script, but this would be a good alternate solution.